# Flutter: How to display a form with listview.builder properly?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I have a MessageDetailPage to show a message detail with or without a form. I separated into two stateful widgets. One is MessageDetailMainPage which shows the basic details, and the other one is MessageDetailFormDisplayPage to show the form of the Message.

Here is the MessageDetailMainPage:

```
child: Scaffold(
 appBar: AppBar(),
 body: SafeArea(
  child: Column(
   children: <Widget> [
    Text(message.title),
    Row(message.detail),
    Divider(),
    MessageDetailFormDisplayPage(
     messageID: widget.messageID
    )
  ]
 )
)
```

Here is the MessageDetailFormDisplayPage:
I used Future Builder to load the form and it is summarized below:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return FutureBuilder(
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
   switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
    case ConnectionState.none:
     return Container(
      child: Text("Please check your connection!"),
     );
    default:
     return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
       itemCount: questions.length,
       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
         children: [
          Text(question.questionTitle),
          Form(
           child: TextFormField(),
          )
         ]
        )
       }
      )
     )
```

The point is that there is an 'submit' button at the end of the form. And I cannot use Column to wrap the Expanded in MessageDetailFormDisplayPage. I guess it is because the Column is nested in another Column, so how can I add the button?

Comment: You should have a look at the Form widget and using a form key